# Ansible lineinfile - append to end of line without overwriting

Tags: ansible

How do I append a list of a groups to the end of a line without overwriting what is already there?

```
- name: "Updating sssd"
  hosts: temp
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    usergroups:
      - operations

  tasks:
  - name: "Add Group to sssd"
    lineinfile:
      dest: /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
      regexp: '^simple_allow_groups'
      line: "simple_allow_groups = {{usergroups | join(',')}}"
      backrefs: yes
```

My intention for this code is to take the line

*simple_allow_groups = admins,developers*

and end with

*simple_allow_groups = admins,developers,operations*

however, the actual result is:

*simple_allow_groups = operations*

Note that I cannot use *regexp: '^simple_allow_groups' = admins,developers* because each server may vary in what groups are already listed here.

Answer (score 2):

Just add one line

```
- name: "Updating sssd"
  hosts: temp
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    usergroups:
      - operations
      - "{{ lookup('ini', 'simple_allow_groups type=properties file=/etc/sssd/sssd.conf') }}"

  tasks:
  - name: "Add Group to sssd"
    lineinfile:
      dest: /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
      regexp: '^simple_allow_groups'
      line: "simple_allow_groups = {{usergroups | join(',')}}"
      backrefs: yes
```

**Some Update**

To make sure `usergroups` unique

```
line: "simple_allow_groups = {{usergroups|flatten|unique | join(',')}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a separate lineinfile task beforehand, but running it in check mode. Example:

```
- name: "Get currently allowed groups from SSSD config"
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
    regexp: '^simple_allow_groups'
    state: absent
  check_mode: yes
  register: existing_groups
```

Then modify the `line:` value in your current task to incorporate `{{ existing_groups}}` and add a conditional like `when: existing_groups is changed`